# AODV Routing Protocol - Route Reply

Tags: pcap, adhoc

I have a AODV pcap file which shows me some RREP packets with both destination and Originator IP address to be the same.
Is it correct or this could possibly be an error. 
My sample pcap file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwbFcIF60n0bQmI3ME5VMGc3RHc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

RREP with same D and O are hello messages